# I occasionally get such an error "the object has been modified" when I update node or deploy with client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I occasionally get such an error "the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" when I update node or deploy with client-go.My goal is that adding a taint/toleration and a label to one node/deployment.

some people said should use

```
err = retry.RetryOnConflict(retry.DefaultBackoff, func() error {})
```

,but it seems that does not work.

```
func AddFaultToleration(deploy *appsv1.Deployment, ns string, client kubernetes.Interface) (*appsv1.Deployment, error) {

    updateDeploy, err := client.AppsV1().Deployments(ns).Get(deploy.Name, metav1.GetOptions{})
    if updateDeploy == nil || err != nil {
        return deploy, fmt.Errorf("Failed to get latest version of Deployment: %v", err)
    }

    effect := apiv1.TaintEffectNoExecute
    updateDeploy.Spec.Template.Spec.Tolerations = append(updateDeploy.Spec.Template.Spec.Tolerations, apiv1.Toleration{
        Key:      ToBeFaultTaintKey,
        Value:    ToBeFaultTaintValue,
        Effect:   effect,
        Operator: apiv1.TolerationOpEqual,
    })

    updatedDeployWithTolera, err := client.AppsV1().Deployments(ns).Update(updateDeploy)
    if err != nil || updatedDeployWithTolera == nil {
        return deploy, fmt.Errorf("failed to update deploy %v after adding toleration: %v", deploy.Name, err)
    }

    log.Info("Successfully added toleration on pod:", updatedDeployWithTolera.Name)
    return updatedDeployWithTolera, nil
}
```

Comment: Are you running same code from multiple processes? you got the latest deployment just before updating the version. It's very unlikely that the deployment is got updated within this fraction of moment. I tried the function. This works fine for me.

Comment: The error is happening because the object got modified in between GETTER and update time period.

Comment: @MarufTuhin Thanks for your reply, I have solved the problem. the reason is that the err of conflict is hided by "updatedDeployWithTolera, err := client.AppsV1().Deployments(ns).Update(updateDeploy)
    if err != nil || updatedDeployWithTolera == nil {
        return deploy, fmt.Errorf("failed to update deploy %v after adding toleration: %v", deploy.Name, err)}".

Comment: So the function of retry.RetryOnConflict doesn't work.

Comment: glad that you found the problem. Go ahead and add the solution here in answer box and accept that answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. the reason is that the err of conflict is hided by

```
updatedDeployWithTolera, err := client.AppsV1().Deployments(ns).Update(updateDeploy) if err != nil || updatedDeployWithTolera == nil { return deploy, fmt.Errorf("failed to update deploy %v after adding toleration: %v", deploy.Name, err)}
```

,So the function of retry.RetryOnConflict doesn't work.